# Entity reference selection by view

Tags: 7, views

I have two content types, Location and Offer. The Offer type has an entity reference field that points to one or more Locations.

A user of my Merchant role may create Location and Offer nodes. When creating an offer, they need to select from the list of Location nodes that they created.

I created a view with an "Entity Reference Source" display to build the Merchant's list of Locations when creating Offers. I limited the Locations to this Merchant by a relationship between author (of the Location) and currently logged in user.

Now, I need Administrator users to be able to edit Offers. The problem is that the view creates a list of the Administrator's Locations instead of the author Merchant's Locations.

How can I supply a list of entities to the locations entity reference field that is the current user's Locations when an Offer is being created and the author's Locations when an Administrator edits?

Comment: I've answered a similar question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933). See a [full guide with screenshots](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933). Hopefully it will answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a way to pass a contextual filter from the current page to the entity selection view.

Currently an argument can sadly only be static.

However there is a patch that allows you to add an argument using a token provided by the current page you are on.

You can find the patch here: https://drupal.org/node/1699378#comment-6809760

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Views Arguments](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arguments) module with the default argument callback. Your callback can return the argument exception value (typically the string `all`) which forces the view to skip the argument and return all results. This can be done when the current user is admin otherwise the current user id is returned.