# Entity Reference View Widget problem with add selective

Tags: views, entities

I am using a content type which uses a field as "Views" Entity Reference View Widget. When I click "add selective" or "add .. and close" in form of this widget, it's just redirect to `http://localhost/denwer`.

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you for answer, kiamlaluno.

details of question:
1. I create a view with type display "Entity Reference View Widget" as table of taxonomy term
(after create view in this view besides display name of views "Entity Reference View Widget" no more information that it use "Entity Reference View Widget" - in Format just show that it's table (grid etc..)
2. Create content type
in content type create field:
- type filed "Entity Reference"
- widget "view"

after create field in description of module "Entit.. widget" says that "on the next page select your View from the dropdown" but there is no dropdown in which can choose my view (picture below)

[image]

if just click "save" created view chosen
(picture below)
[image]

[image]

then i use default settings and save settings of field.

Next step  - Add node of created type and here is problem:
- i see field with widget, can click add item
- then i see "widget form with created view"
But if click on buttom "add selected item" - it's just go to page "/localhost /denwer" 
and of cause nothing add in "node add"

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not clear what `http://localhost/denwer` means, nor from where that URL is taken from. You should edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar issue by changing the display type to "Entity Reference" (not "Entity Reference View Widget") and using using the ER Widget only for the view checkbox selection field.

[Here is a detailed step-by-step guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933) to a solution which worked for me using the latest Drupal 7 dev version of the ER Widget module.