# Remove tagging on node view

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I am building a social network with Drupal. I have the following requirement:

1. A person who adds a post can tag his friends when adding his posts.
2. His tagged friends can untag themself when viewing the post.

Requirement #1 was met by the amazingly efficient entity reference view widget ([see my recent answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933)).

But how to achieve requirement #2 ?

[image: tagging]

What is the best way to implement such a feature?

1. Is there any inline editing tool (such as the [edit](https://drupal.org/project/edit) module) for entity reference fields?
2. Does [editablefields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) really works for Drupal 7?
3. Should I just implement it using the [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module?
4. Any other approach?

Please advise.

Comment: You could do it custom by appending the link to the tag with the term/node id in the callback url and processing it with ajax/js.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to define a [custom field formatter](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7) but it didn't find the hook.

In the end it was much easier to use the [Entity Reference Views Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_views_formatter) module, then theme the view field to add the desired behavior to the relevant link. I used the rules_link module to define the untag link, then added the untag link into the field's theme. Next time I should probably use a tpl.php file as well.

```
File: views-view-field--with--block--field-with.tpl.php

<?php 
  global $user; 
  $my_uid = $user->uid;   
  $node = node_load ($row->nid);
  $results = db_query(      // Load the field without loading the entire node. 
    "SELECT field_with_target_id 
       FROM field_data_field_with 
      WHERE entity_id = :entity_id", 
    array(':entity_id' =>$row->nid));


  $lines = "";
  foreach($results as $result) {
    $uid = $result->field_with_target_id;
    $account = user_load((int)$uid);
    $rendered = l(mymodule_get_realname($account), "user/$uid");
    $untag = "";
    if ($uid == $my_uid) {
      $rules_link = rules_link_load('un_tag_me');
      $untag = render(rules_link_render_link($rules_link,$row->nid));
      $untag = str_replace (
        array("<div ", 'title="x"'), 
        array("<div title='Un-tag me'", 'title="Un-tag me"'), 
        $untag);
    }
    $line = "<div class='field-item'>$rendered $untag</div>"; 
    $lines .= $line; 
  } 
  if (!empty($lines)) {
    $output = "<div class='field-items'>$lines</div>";
  }   
  print $output; 
 ?>
```