# Unpublished content is displaying in entity referenced fields

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I am using entity reference to refer another content type. But in the list I am getting unpublished content also. Because I have given permission to view Unpublished content, but I don't want to show them here. So how can I restrict those content from displaying in Entity referred field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding entity reference field to the content type,

In Field Setting--> Entity selection-->Mode -->Select Views and create a view by filtering only Published content, and assign the same to "View used to select the entities *"

Hope this will help you in building views [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933)

Comment: This one will work thank u for this. But is there any coding I can do to achieve this.

Comment: Create an hook_form_alter  with this similar kind of code will help you      $options = array($entity_node->nid => $entity_node->title);
     $form['field_ref_type'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']['#options'] =  $options;
     $form['field_ref_type'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $entity_node->nid;