# How can I display a custom field for node reference in another content type?

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a node with custom fields that I would like to pull into a different content type. I do not want to display the full node, only one or two fields. Currently with Node Reference I only have options to display the title, ID, or the full node.

My content type has the option to list unlimited nodes of this type, so the end result could possibly have multiple node ids.

I think the best way to do this would be with a custom ph formatter but I am a little lost on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for the entity reference field  with the fields whichever you want to list.

Below is the setting for the entity reference to select a view

In Field Setting--> Entity selection-->Mode -->Select Views and assign the same to "View used to select the entities *"

[Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933) is the link to create a view of entity reference type link,

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been playing around with this all day, but I am still running into the same issue. I can't get it to pull only the field I have set up in my Entity Reference view. I can still render the title or the full node, but not my custom field alone. I did have some luck setting the view mode to teaser and then setting up my field as a teaser, but it's still not exactly what I am looking for because the title remains.